# Individual date, month and year dropdowns in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to create a form in bootstrap, I have completed the majority of it however I am getting stuck on the last part. What I need is 3 dropdown menus containing the users date of birth. Day, Months and Year.

I have looked through the bootstrap docs and cannot find any help for this.

I would like to look like this: https://gyazo.com/96c8be19718dbffef7302ea30a7eb343

The arrow dropdown is a custom image I made. I was wondering if it would be possible to have that instead of a default arrow.

Thanks a lot :)

```
                <form class="form">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="first-name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="email-address" class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-address">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="last-name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    <label for="confirm-email-address" class="control-label">Confirm Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirm-email-address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                    // dropdowns would go here
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: As you're using bootstrap, wouldn't an actual datepicker be a better choice for your form? https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: No unfortunately my hands are tied and it has to look like the image I provided.

Comment: http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/ or http://icklechris.github.io/jquery-date-dropdowns/

Comment: How would I place this into my code? @NullPointerException $("example1").dateDropdowns();

Comment: You need to include these js plugins into your code. read their documentation

Comment: <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <input type="hidden" id="example3">
                <script>
                $("example1").dateDropdowns({
                    defaultValue: "2010-02-17"
                });
                </script>

I tried that but it doesn't work?

Comment: @NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

I made a full example you only need is put the correct class for each element.

To initialize the date time you have to use this

```
$(".date-dropdowns").dateDropdowns();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/dszkt041/1/

also read the documentation about the plugin

http://icklechris.github.io/jquery-date-dropdowns/