# Can I make this in javascript + html/css? (image)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

So basically its a drop down with the button next to it containing an arrow image, obviously when the buttow is clicked it opens a dropdown menu.

I have no idea how I can make this, if it helps I am using bootstrap but I've seen nothing which can help me in the docs.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to make it with javascript or with html/css? The `<select>` tag is used for this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, you can make it. I suggest doing some basic tutorials on web programming.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It will help other developers who are seeking to help you if you posted an example of something you have tried, rather than asking people to just do it for you.

Comment: i am pretty sure you have posted the exact same image in another thread yesterday asking a question along the lines of bootstrap

Comment: @Ji_in_coding [They did.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046252/individual-date-month-and-year-dropdowns-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried doing? I realize that you said nothing in the bootstrap documentation can help you, but I recommend reviewing it again. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns  You should even be able to copy and paste the code, but also make sure you have the proper bootstrap css and javascript files/pathways.

Comment: Yes I see this but I need the dropdown to have a custom image within a button isntead of the default dropdown :)

Comment: try using the <span> tag for your image

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ripper1992/72v2o4be/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="appearance-select">
    <option disabled selected>Select...</option>
    <option>First Option</option>
    <option>Second Option</option>
    <option>Third Option</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #appearance-select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        background: url(http://www.mycityway.com/now/img/dropDownArrow.png) no-repeat #eeeeee;
        background-position: 210px center;
        width: 240px;
        height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        background-size: 28px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Ah yes this is what I've been looking for? How would I change it so the button has a different background from the dropdown? like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/U3P74.png

I have changed the no-repeat #eeeee to my colour but it does the whole thing, thanks :)

Comment: In this case, the arrow, is an image. So, if you want the i.stack.imgur.com/U3P74.png arrow, you'll need to crop it, and place in a location that your application can see (online or local), change this URL in the **backround** property. Also, you'll ned to change the **background-size** and **background-position** property.